# Class Not registered Exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, vb6-migration

Recently i migrate the project from vb6 to vb.net with framework 2.0 in visual studio 2008 in xp system it is working fine in that. After that i changed the framework to 3.5 and opened the project in vs2010 in xp only there also it is working fine for me.

Now i changed my Operating system to windows 7. here i opened the project i got some issues i solved and then build it it is succeed. but when i am trying to run i got error like  below

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: My issue was solved... I found some dll dependecies in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs more detail.  Please include the inner exception details and the call stack - this will help to determine which component is throwing the error.

The error itself is clear - one of the classes you are using is not registered on the Win7 system (ie : missing DLL, etc).  This could be because the component/library was never installed on the Win7 system or the installation is corrupt.  It could also be because it is a 32-bit component and you are targeting `AnyCPU` or `x64` in your compilation options.

Comment: The innerException is like this only..                             Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))     yes my intension is to run on win7 so i am targeting to AnyCPU.

Comment: @user1934161 The call stack associated with the exception would be very helpful - it should tell you exactly where the issue is.  Are you using any 32-bit libraries?

Comment: i have the same problem in converted project to visual studio 2012 and my dll in AnsweringMachine project for this company .... Kaed KDTele Tools and when i config my project setting properties >> compile > target cpu 86 bit (this is worked properly and error troubleshoot) thanks everyone