# VB6 to vb.net Class Not registered Exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, vb6

As my first task working with vb.net, I was assigned the job of migrating a VB6 project over to vb.net using Visual Studio 2008. I am now working with Visual Studio 2017 and have gone through and cleared up all of the Upgrade Warnings that the conversion process gave me. The only remaining issues I have are with two instances of "Class Not Registered" Exceptions.

Things to note:

- the original vb6 program was on a Windows XP machine. I am currently working on a Windows 7 64bit system.
- I have read a couple of other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478117/class-not-registered-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680036/class-not-registered-exception), but I haven't been able to solve my issue.
- This warning is more specifically related to a Design view of a form

I believe the issue is probably something to do with a missing dll, as I had to move the source code to another computer to do the debugging.

Here is the call stack if anyone can help point me in the right direction:

```
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) 
Instances of this error (2)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.set_Site(ISite value)
at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your ActiveX control registered? You still have to ensure an correct registration of COM components. Then you can use them - from within 32 bit executables (change your app setup to x86)

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I changed Compile Platform to be x86. I have a list of the Reference DLL's used in my project. A few of those DLL's I just copied from the old winxp computer I took the source code from. How do I check to see if they are registered?

Comment: If you just copied the files, they are NOT registered. Use the RegSvr32 tool from windows to register your activex controls.Depending on the control (you didn´t mention it) it may be necessary to use the setup program of the control (maybe there is more then just a dll).

Comment: @nabuchodonossor My best guess is that the DLL that is causing this issue is Interop.PulseLabShop by bruel & kjaer. I copied it over from the winxp machine and haven't done anything else with it, other than adding it as a reference to my project. When I went a tried to register it I got the message: _The module was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found_ After some googling it seems that either the DLLRegisterServer function doesn't exist in the DLL (I can't verify that at this time, I need Admin Access to download a program to check) or this DLL doesn't need registering

Comment: the best way would be to use the old setup program of the pulselabshop. It should handle the problem. Is there an ocx file for this pulselabshop? or a tlb file? sorry, I don´t know the product you are using, so I can only make guessings.

Comment: There are a lot of products on the bruel&kjaer page - what exacty are you using? There is also description how to install pulse labshop. there is a dongle mentioned. Maybe the dongle is missing?